# On screen soft mouse?

Tags: mouse

Is it possible to have a touch control of the mouse cursor in Android instead of the use of a hardware mouse?
Maybe something like the soft keyboard?

Comment: What do you mean? Like when you connctna mouse via USB OTG?

Comment: Yes, but without a hardware mouse, just using software.

Comment: What would be the point? It would be jumping to wherever you touched. If its for a screen cast, the screencast app on the market allows touch symbol. There is an option in ICS and above in developer options as well.

Comment: It can be useful on special occasions when you need high precision while still seeing were exactly you are clicking, like graphic editing.

Comment: If I may be blunt, I suggest you get an OTG adapter and connect a mouse.

Comment: Do you mean something like Chrome Remote Desktop's cursor control, but directly in your android device?

Answer (score 2):

As Liam W suggested, have you tried the any of the developer options? On at least 4.0 (ICS) and higher (and perhaps older versions, someone else will have to verify) in *Settings > Developer Options* check out *Show Touches* and *Pointer Location* (screenshots and short descriptions [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/ice-cream-sandwich-puts-additional-debug-tools-in-the-hands-of-developers/1275)). Neither are exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps you'll find them useful.

Comment: Show pointer was introduced in ICS :-)

Comment: I'm using older Android version and my hardware isn't capable of ICS, so I'm looking for a mouse emulator app..